# Discord.py - Give Someone a Role, but in the PM's and with the Server ID

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to do something like that:
If someone writes the command !GiveRole to the Bot in PM's, the next thing should be the Server ID, after that the Role, would something like that be possible, because i know that it is not hard to give someone a role with the bot, but is it possible to do it with the PM's and Server ID?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but I'm not sure if it's gonna work.

```
@bot.command()
async def giverole(ctx, guild, role):
    if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel) == False: # Checking if this is a DM Channel
        return
    guild = bot.get_guild(int(guild)) # Getting guild
    if guild is None: # Checking if the guild exists
        await ctx.send("Invalid guild ID!")
        return
    role = guild.get_role(int(role)) # Getting role
    if role is None: # Checking if the role exists
       await ctx.send("Invalid role ID!")
       return
    await guild.get_member(ctx.guild.id).add_roles(role) # Give role to member
    await ctx.send(f"You received **{role.name}** role!")
```

Comment: Getting this error:     await guild.get_member(ctx.guild.id).add_roles(role) # Give role to member
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
Any fix for that?

Comment: Oh, replace remove ctx.guild.id by guild.id. It was trying to get the id of the DMChannel, which is None.

Comment: New Error:     await guild.get_member(guild.id).add_roles(role) # Give role to member
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Comment: try ```await guild.get_member(guild.id).add_roles(role)``` to ```await guild.get_member(ctx.author.id).add_roles(role)```